# Is accessing state in different component affect the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which return a form to CRUD with a state object. It perform well with data I entered manually. But when I update it with another object which I get data from excel. It doesn't perform as I expected. It doesn't access to the state object which clearly has data.

Here's the structure of it.

```
const ManageABC = () => {
    const [obj, setObj] = useState({});
    const [excelLoadedItems, setExcelLoadedItems] = useState({}); // loaded

    useEffect(() => {
        // fetching data for obj
    }, []);

    const ExcelListItem = ({index, name, onAdd}) => {
        return (
            <li key={index} onClick={onAdd}>{name}</li>
        );
    }

    const handleOnAdd = (values) => {
        // return a promise to add the item to obj
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            console.log(obj); 
            // this log the obj when data entered manually but not when  
            // this function called from handleOnItemExcelAdd()
            // which is important cuz I need it to check the condition below
            if (values["id"] in obj) {
                // not add
                console.log('obj has this value');
                resolve(true);
            } else {
                // add
                console.log("obj doesn't have this value");
                resolve(false);
            }
        }
    }

    const handleOnExcelItemAdd = (values, event) => {
        handleOnAdd(values).then((res) => {
            // remove li item if user says yes
            if (res) {
                const thisEle = event.target;
                thisEle.closest("li").remove();
            }
        });
    }

    const handleExcelLoad(file) {
        // read excel then
        setExcelLoadedItems(
            data.map((item, index) => (
                <ExcelListItem
                    index={index}
                    name={item["name"]}
                    // this add and remove li good but it does not get the obj state to check the condition, the obj state remain nothing
                    onAdd={(event) => handleOnExcelItemAdd(item, event)}
                />
            ))
        );
    }

    return (
        {excelLoadedItems}
        {obj.map(
            // mapped out obj
        )}
    );
}
```

So because it does not check for condition, it auto modify the exist key in `obj`

Comment: should ```useState(() => {// fetching data for obj}, []);``` be ```useEffect```? Also, if you are using ```[]``` in ```useEffect```, this will only trigger once.

Comment: Let's put this away. I just try to explain my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You are just modifying elements from the actual DOM level. Since React has the mechanism of the virtual DOM. I guess this may cause the problem of bypassing this mechanism.

To let React knows that the DOM should be updated, use your `setState` hook to do so.

```
const handleOnExcelItemAdd = (values, event) => {
        handleOnAdd(values).then((res) => {
            if (res) {
                const thisEle = event.target;
                thisEle.closest("li").remove();

                //construct a new object here
                const yourNewObject = //some operation
 
                //setObj makes the component render again, you will then see the new changes
                setObj(yourNewObject);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: No, this function get the job done. Which is add the item to obj. But it call the `handleOnAdd` couldn't access the state `obj`. Which lead to checking the condition wrong.

Comment: @Gr4y ```setObj``` hasn't been used. Not sure the ```obj``` is the real updated one. I suggest use ```console.log(values);```  in the ```Promise``` to see what truly passed in.

Comment: Like I said, the `obj` is updated and has the data I needed. But the `handleOnAdd` I call inside `handleOnExcelItemAdd` does not access to the data of `obj`. The manual data input logged the data of `obj` but when I call `handleOnExcelAdd` it logged out nothing